# How do I make a resizable window form or winform with controls in Visual C++?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, resize

I just wondering about my windows Application. When i re-size windows form that time my Form controls should re-size. Can any body tell me how to do this in Vc++

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your controls has an anchor property, set this property on each control to their relative position on the form  then when you resize the form the controls will move and stay "Aligned"

i hope this is what you are referring to, and that this helps